# How to send and receive SnapshotStateList through bundle in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a list of `SnapshotStateList` and I want to pass through `Bundle` but I am getting error.

```
@Parcelize
data class Movie(val name:String) : Parcelable
```

**openNewActivity**

```
private fun openNewActivity(activity: Activity, movieList: SnapshotStateList<Movie>) {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("MovieList", movieList)
}
```

Getting error on `movieList`

```
Type mismatch.
Required: ArrayList<out Parcelable!>?
Found: SnapshotStateList<Movie>
```

Comment: [`SnapshotStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList) is not an `ArrayList`. The closest analogue to your current code would be to try using `ArrayList(movieList)` to create an `ArrayList<Movie>` with your current `SnapshotStateList` contents. Far better would be to eliminate the other activity or not attempt to pass a list of movies between activities.

Comment: So I'll change the my `movieList` to `ArrayList(movieList)` and pass to another activity?

Comment: That should compile and run. However, passing model data like that between activities has been an anti-pattern for years.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any related document  about `passing model data like that between activities has been an anti-pattern`? So I can show my team not to use that.

Comment: In terms of official docs, it is covered piecemeal, such as [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data). Ian Lake and other Googlers point out the anti-pattern a lot here in Stack Overflow. The `TransactionTooLargeException` you can get from `Intent` extras has been the topic of many Stack Overflow questions, such as [this one](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data).